# Laravel Route [admin.delete-post] not defined - i defined this route

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing

I use a path in Laravel that I have defined.
But it gives me an undefined message
I have checked all the routes.
I even cleared the cache.
This is very unusual for me because my other paths are working in the same way

this my body

```
    @extends('layouts.master')
    @section('content')
        @if(Session::has('info'))
        <div class="bg-dark text-white">
            <p>box:{{Session::get('info')}}</p>
        </div>
        @endif
        <div>
            <a class="btn btn-dark" href="{{route('admin.new-post')}}">New Post</a>
            <br /><br />
            @foreach($posts as $post)
            <div class="text-center">
                <div>
                    <h1>{{$post->title}}</h1>
                    <p>
                        {{$post->content}}
                    </p>
                </div>
                <a class="btn btn-dark" href="{{route('admin.edit-post',['id' => $post->id])}}">Edit Post</a>
                <a class="btn btn-dark" href="{{route('admin.delete-post',['id' => $post->id])}}">Delete Post</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        @endforeach
    @endsection
```

this my route

```
Route::group(['prefix'=>'admin'],function(){

    Route::get('',[
        'uses' => 'App\Http\Controllers\PostController@getAdminIndex',
        'as' => 'admin'
    ]);

    Route::get('new-post',[
        'uses' => 'App\Http\Controllers\PostController@getAdminCreate',
        'as' => 'admin.new-post'
    ]);

    Route::post('create', [
        'uses' => 'App\Http\Controllers\PostController@postAdminCreate',
        'as' => 'admin.create-post'
    ]);

    Route::get('edit-post/{id}',[
        'uses' => 'App\Http\Controllers\PostController@getAdminEdit',
        'as' => 'admin.edit-post'
    ]);

    Route::post('edit',[
        'uses' => 'App\Http\Controllers\PostController@postAdminUpdate',
        'as' => 'admin.update'
    ]);

    Route::get('delete-post/{id}', 'App\Http\Controllers\PostController@postDelete')
        ->name('admin.delete-post');

});
```

> This is my control, but I get the error of not finding the path.
> Everything is simple in all the code.
> There is no ambiguity in the codes.
> Thanks for your effort for me

````
        <?php
        
        namespace App\Http\Controllers;
        
        use Illuminate\Http\Request;
        use App\Models\Post;
        use Illuminate\Session\Store;
        use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
        
        class PostController extends Controller
        {
            public function getIndex(Store $session){
                $posts = Post::all();
                return view("blog.home",['posts' => $posts]);
            }
            public function getAdminIndex(Store $session){
                $posts = Post::all();
                return view("admin.index",['posts' => $posts]);
            }
            public function getPost(Store $session, $id){
                $post = Post::find($id);
                return view("blog.post",['post' => $post]);
            }
            public function getAdminCreate(Store $session){
                return view('admin.new-post');
            }
            public function getAdminEdit(Store $session, $id){
                $post = Post::find($id);
                return view("admin.edit-post",['post' => $post , 'postId' => $id]);
            }
            public function postAdminCreate(Store $session, Request $request){
                $this->validate($request,[
                    'title' => 'Required | min:5',
                    'content' => 'Required | min:10'
                ]);
                $post = new Post([
                    'title' => $request->input('title'),
                    'content' => $request->input('content')
                ]);
                $post->save();
                return redirect()->route('admin')->with('info','post created, title is :'.
                $request->input('title'));
            }
            public function postAdminUpdate(Store $session, Request $request){
                $this->validate($request,[
                    'title' => 'Required | min:5',
                    'content' => 'Required | min:10'
                ]);
                $post = Post::find($request->input('id'));
                $post->title = $request->input('title');
                $post->content = $request->input('content');
                $post->save();
                return redirect()
                    ->route('admin')
                    ->with('info','post edited, title is :'. $request
                            ->input('title'));
            }
            public function postDelete($id){
                $post = Post::find($id);
                $post->delete();
                return redirect()->route('admin.index')->with('info', 'Delete your post');
            }
        
        }
    ```
            this my Exception 
            
            > Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException
            Route [admin.delete-post] not defined. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\my-laravel\resources\views\admin\index.blade.php)`

thank you of all
````

Comment: What version of laravel is this?

Comment: have you tried using the `as` keyword? Just like the rest of your routes?

Comment: laravel-8 . i use of route name for all route

Comment: Please add detailed information about the error message you get, `an undefined message` is not very helpful. Also, add your controller so that we can rule out a missing action method.

Comment: Hi . I also added a controller to the above code.
The codes are very simple and fluent

Answer (score -1):

what I noticed:

```
    Route::post('edit',[
        'uses' => 'App\Http\Controllers\PostController@postAdminUpdate',
        'as' => 'admin.update'
    ]);

    Route::get('delete-post/{id}', 'App\Http\Controllers\PostController@postDelete')
        ->name('admin.delete-post');
```

In the laravel documentation only lists the keyword as for naming routes up to version 5.3. I'm not sure if it still works in laravel 8!? Maybe you name all your routes with name instead of as.

Instead of "as", use "name" as the routing name. Which would be correct in itself. But try it with "as".

And maybe important for this case: `php artisan route:clear`

And: Are you sure that you use get Method for delete?

Comment: I used "as" and got the same error again

Comment: @sinamohsenian and if you use only name ? and important: `php artisan route:clear`

Comment: thank you .  I was really disappointed. Thank you . It worked

Comment: @sinamohsenian cool! what was it now. route cache or the name route definition with name?

Comment: route cache . thank you